# Nuget package doesn't install into individual projects?

Tags: nuget

I've added several Nuget packages to my multi-project solution with no issues.  However, when I add this package -- **ews.x64** (Exchange Web Services API) -- *Nuget does not allow me to add it to any particular project*.

The packages subfolder is created normally:

```
D:\TFSSource\Exchange\Utilities\Src\ExchangePurge\packages\EWS.x64.1.2
```

but when you attempt to manage the solution's installed packages, the "Manage Nuget Packages" dialog only offers an **Uninstall** button for this particular package.  All the other packages have the **Manage** button allowing them to be added to the individual projects.

Also interesting is the fact that this package appears in a **packages.config** file under a newly created solution folder called **.nuget**?  Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a solution-level package, a package that doesn't have project specific content or libraries. The package is probably installed correctly and available to all projects at once.

source:[NuGet FAQ](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/nuget-faq#What_is_the_difference_between_a_project-level_package_and_a_solution-level_package%3f)

Comment: You certainly appear to be right.  Not sure why, though, that this would be set up that way since the purpose of the package is to provide a reference to a single assembly -- Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll.  I'll pursue that with the Exchange Development forum.  Thanks.

p.s. From your link: "Typically, a solution-level package installs new commands that can be called from within the Package Manager Console window".